# How to execute scrapy from php on Parallel?

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrapy, gnu-parallel

I have 90 urls in an array

```
[url1,url2,url3,  ... , url90]
```

I want to have **3 spiders** who works at the same time and pass 1 url to each one, so, my first instance of Scrapy gets url1, the second one gets url2 and the third one gets url3, and when the first one will finish his job he will get url4.

i used [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) but if there is another software better i will use that.

i tried this one in php because i should launch my scrapy from PHP

```
exec (for url in urlsTab | parallel -j 3 scrapy crawl mySpider -a url {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this (untested):

```
$parallel = popen("parallel -j 3 scrapy crawl mySpider","w");
foreach($urlsTab as $url) {
    fwrite($parallel,$url+"\n");
}
close $parallel;
```